# List of 10 digit strings where every 4 digit substring is unique

Tags: c++, algorithm, math, graph-theory

In a past competition, I was asked to generate 10 digit strings using digits from 0 to 9 once each.  Any four-digit substring used in a string cannot be used again.

What is the highest number of unique strings you can generate using these rules? 
List them.

*Example:*

If you use a string 0243697518 in your list, you can not generate  strings contain 0243, 2436, 4369, 3697, 6975, 9751 and 7518

---

To solve the problem, I have written a c++ program, simply it scans all permutation of "0123456789" and add them into a solution list if 4 digit sub-strings of the code has not been used before. But the problem of my algorithm is that the size of solution list varies by depending on your starting point that you add into the list first. If I start adding into list from "0123456789", list ends up with 504 entries which is not the maximum asked. I really wonder how to solve this question, any help highly appreciated. I'm open to hear your mathematical solution or any algorithm suggestions to generate the list asked.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>
#include <vector>
#include <set>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

void main(void)
{
    set<string> substring_list; // holds the list of used 4 digit sub-strings
    set<string> solution_list;

    string code = "0123456789";
    do 
    {
        vector<string> subs;
        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
        {
            // adds all 4  digits sub-strings used in the code
            subs.push_back(code.substr(i, 4));
        }

        if ((substring_list.find(subs[0]) == substring_list.end()) &&
            (substring_list.find(subs[1]) == substring_list.end()) &&
            (substring_list.find(subs[2]) == substring_list.end()) &&
            (substring_list.find(subs[3]) == substring_list.end()) &&
            (substring_list.find(subs[4]) == substring_list.end()) &&
            (substring_list.find(subs[5]) == substring_list.end()) &&
            (substring_list.find(subs[6]) == substring_list.end()))
        {
            // if all substrings are unique and not used before
            // then add code into solution list
            solution_list.insert(code);

            // add newly added code's substrings to substring list.
            for (auto s: subs)
            {
                substring_list.insert(s);
            }

        }
    } while (next_permutation(code.begin(), code.end()));

    cout << solution_list.size() << endl;
}
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about mathematical algorithms, not their precise implementation. It doesn't matter what language you are using, as this stands it still belongs on maths.stackexchange.com.

Comment: I have some mathematical figures give idea about what maximum size should be. But these figures are not helping me to generate actual list or not giving a light about algorithm to be used. In my situation math and algorithm should come together.

Comment: I wonder if my thinking is correct: There are in total `9x8x7x6` substrings of length 4 (using digits 0 to 9), each of these substrings can appear only once in your solution. Also, there are 7 substrings of length 4 in a string of length 10. Therefore, the maximum number of strings that you can generate is `9x8x7x6 / 7` which is 432.

Comment: your thinking is correct but it is 10x9x8x7/7 because of 10 digits not 9. this thinking also assumes that you use each unique sub-strings once in your final solution list. This assumption should be supported by an algorithm whether it is possible but how?

Comment: Forget about code. Think. How many 4 digit substrings are there in a 10 digit number? How does this bound your answer?

Comment: @Colonel Panic - see we can have 10x9x8x7=5040 different sub-strings. each 10 digit numbers consist of 7 of sub-strings. It means that you can not produce more than 5040/7 pcs ten digit numbers fit into the rule. But that doesn't mean you can produce that much as well.

Comment: puzzling.stackexchange.com might also be a good place for this one.

Comment: from help center: What topics can I ask about here?
a specific programming problem, or
a software algorithm, or
... then you’re in the right place to ask your question! hah

Comment: @AirsourceLtd This question is most indeed about programming. Generating the list would definitely require a computer (notice that the OP asked for the actual list - "and I need the list of them"), and finding an algorithm to generate it efficiently would definitely require computer programming skills.

Comment: @MehmetFide FYI - According to your method of calculation, for 5-element strings and two-digit substrings, there could be a solution of `5*4/4 = 5` strings. I wrote a program that tested all 190,578,024 5-string combinations from the permutations of "12345" - there were no 5-string solutions. I'm not sure if that means there would be no solution to your question that is as large as your math calculation but clearly the calculation does not imply a solution of that magnitude. (For the case of 4-element strings and two-digit substrings, there are six solutions of `4*3/3 = 4` strings.)

Comment: I wrote a little php script to do some testing. The result: If you randomize the order of the 10 digit strings I find between 605 and 631 strings as solution. Maybe it is possible to improve a random solution bei deleting some of the 10 digit strings and retry finding 10 digit strings containing only the remaining 4 digit strings.

Comment: @גלעדברקן - there is a full list solution, this is reported officially.

Comment: @AbcAeffchen - I believed that there is a deterministic way to the solution. What I reached so far is 633.

Comment: I start thinking that this question is related with Graph Theory and Hamiltonian path.

Comment: @MehmetFide If the full list is published, it might be helpful to see it - can you please show us the list or a link to it?

Comment: @גלעדברקן - Unfortunately no, they didn't want to share the list including solution way. But they confirmed the list exists.

Comment: I'm not sure how much this might help but we can be certain that each 504 four-digit substrings with first digit `i` must belong to different strings (e.g., for substrings starting with 0 - `0123, 0125..., 0987`). The other 216 distinct strings must contain `i` as the 8th, 9th or 10th digit (e.g., last four digits `x0xx, xx0x, or xxx0`).